# How to describe time like "ten to/till eight"

Tags: word-difference

In some [web pages](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/what-time-it) use `to`

> 8:50 (ten to nine)
>   11:40 (twenty to twelve)

And another [web page](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/how-to-tell-time-in-english/) use `till`

> 7:45 is “a quarter till eight“

Are both expression used in UK and US?
Maybe there is some kind of different nuance?

Comment: This is definitely a regional usage; in NYC, I almost invariably hear _to_; when I visit Pennsylvania Dutch Country, I hear _till_ quite a bit more.

Comment: "Of" is another US regional variation (as in "a quarter of eight").  In BrE, though, I've only ever heard "to".

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak for the UK, but in the US all are idiomatic although there may be regional preferences. With the advent of clocks with digital displays, the "7:45" variant may be slowly driving out the "quarter to/of/till eight," especially among younger people.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, "to" is normal. I don't believe I have ever come across "till" from a speaker of British English, though I know it is used by some Americans.